# Loop inside an f-string as a value for an embed

Tags: python, discord.py, f-string

I have a tuple with some values and I want to send them in an embed. They're inside a dictionary like this
`dict = {key: [(1, 2, 3), other values here], other key: [(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), other values here]}`

Now some of the tuples here are of different lengths and it triggers me if I used a loop to add an embed field since discord doesn't allow the name parameter to be false or null yet. If I use a 0 width whitespace character, there's a big space that I'd rather not have. Tried using ternary operators but it didn't work. I also can't have this
`for i in range(0, len(dict) - 1): pass`
since the loop would've already came to an end before I could use it to index the tuple. I also tried doing

`value = f'{tuple[i] for i in range(0, len(tuple) - 1)}'`

but the bot return `<generator object stats.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0000012E94AB3200>` instead of the values inside the tuple.

Edit:

Thanks to the people who answered! It now works, thanks

Comment: put the statement in `[]`:  `f'{[my_tuple[i] for i in range(0, len(my_tuple) - 1)]}'`, also, might not want to name your variable `tuple`

Answer (score 2):

```
tuple[i] for i in range(0, len(tuple) - 1)
```

Is a generator expression, it doesn't produce any values unless consumed by something like a loop or `list()`

You can use the equivalent list-comprehension instead:

```
f'{[tuple[i] for i in range(0, len(tuple) - 1)]}'
```

Or put the generator inside a `list()`

```
f'{list(tuple[i] for i in range(0, len(tuple) - 1))}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your comprehension is not wrapped in `[]` it is technically a generator expression `()` (I think this would have worked in python 2.7 though), try this:

```py
my_tuple = (1, 2, 3, 4)

f'{[my_tuple[i] for i in range(0, len(my_tuple) - 1)]}'
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Also, there are no tuple comprehensions in python because tuples are immutable.